# Font rendering issue using <Font> with Latin letters (ě, š, č, ř, ž) using React Native and Poppins font

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, fonts

I'm facing an issue with font rendering in my React Native project, specifically with Latin letters such as ě, š, č, ř, ž when using the Poppins font. I have defined the font using the following code which is not functioning for latin letters:

```css
<Font
fontFamily="Poppins"
fallbackFontFamily="Verdana"
  webFont={{
   url: "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecnFHGPc.woff2",
   format: "woff2",
  }}
fontWeight={400}
fontStyle="normal"
/>
```

[Different style of ě from the rest of letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wVO7.png)

**Tried:**

I tried using different fontWeights, links and formats.

**Expected:**

Same style of font for whole document with latin letters

[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ajay.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `ě, š, č, ř, ž` are included in the **latin-extended** subset.
You're currently loading the (basic) **latin** subset thus, you see a fallback font.

If you only need the regular version just open the CSS URL in your browser and copy the urls for latin and latin ext from the `@font-face` rules.

Frankly, I haven't found an explanation, how to add multiple unicode ranges in react-native but it should look something like this

```
<Font
    fontFamily="Poppins"
    fallbackFontFamily="Verdana"
    webFont={[
      {
        url: "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecnFHGPc.woff2",
        format: "woff2",
        unicodeRange: "U+0000-00FF, U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+0400-04FF, U+0500-052F, U+0600-06FF, U+0900-097F, U+0A00-0A7F, U+1100-11FF, U+1F00-1FFF",
      },
      {
        url: "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJnecmNE.woff2",
        format: "woff2",
        unicodeRange: "U+0100-02AF, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+1E00-1E9F, U+1EF2-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF",
      },
    ]}
    fontWeight={400}
    fontStyle="normal"
  />
```

```css
/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJnecmNE.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}
```

```html
<h1>Hamburgefons ě, š, č, ř, ž </h1>
```

Otherwise you can also download the complete "unsubsetted" versions.
Keep in mind these files are significantly bigger than a single unicode-range subset (~50KB).

```
"files": {
        "100": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrLPTecnFBGPaTSQ.woff2",
        "100italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiAyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmE3tAOvODSVFF.woff2",
        "200": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLFj_V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "200italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmv1plFd2PQEhcqw.woff2",
        "300": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "300italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLm21llFd2PQEhcqw.woff2",
        "regular": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrFJXUc1NECPY.woff2",
        "italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLecnFBGPaTSQ.woff2",
        "500": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "500italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmg1hlFd2PQEhcqw.woff2",
        "600": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLEj6V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "600italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmr19lFd2PQEhcqw.woff2",
        "700": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "700italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmy15lFd2PQEhcqw.woff2",
        "800": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDD4V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "800italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLm111lFd2PQEhcqw.woff2",
        "900": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLBT5V15vFP-KUEg.woff2",
        "900italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLm81xlFd2PQEhcqw.woff2"
      },
```

Data retrieved using the [developer API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385876/list-all-variable-fonts-from-google-fonts-api/76131378#76131378)